# Gamethrive Onesignal Send push from unit to unit

Tags: push-notification, onesignal

I am considering switching from pushwoosh to gamethrive / onesignal but am a little confused. I am using the Unity SDK and cant see anywhere in the documentation that I am able to sund push from one unit to a specific othe unit. Can anyone help me clarify if this is possible

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 3):

Yes this is possible.

The OneSignal API supports delivering notifications to individual users or groups of users in several ways. In your case, the best way is probably through the device's OneSignal ID (through the `include_player_ids` field in the OneSignal API).

You can send notifications from one device to another by interacting through the OneSignal API either on your own backend server or from the code running in your app. However, in either case, you will need to have a backend server to store a list of the OneSignal ID for each one of your users.

Here's a rough outline of the process:

Part A (First getting the OneSignal ID):

1. A device runs your application for the first time
2. You initialize OneSignal in your application and you receive a new unique OneSignal ID for this new device in a callback
3. You then must store this OneSignal ID on your own backend server somewhere.

Part B (Delivering a message):

1. You wish to send a message to a specific user
2. You ask your backend server for the OneSignal ID of the user who you wish to send a message to.
3. You use the OneSignal API to send a message to the user.

Related links:

[OneSignal Homepage](https://onesignal.com)

[OneSignal Documentation Home](http://documentation.onesignal.com)

[OneSignal Notification Delivery API Documentation](http://documentation.onesignal.com/v2.0/docs/notifications-create-notification)